# Удалить кнопку добавить в корзину по ID продуктов

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Есть сайт на WordPress. Подключен плагин WooCommerce. Как прописать несколько ID в данную функцию, чтобы убрать кнопку `Добавить в корзину` для нескольких товаров?

```
function remove_single_add_to_cart() {
    if (get_the_ID() == 2799) {
        remove_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 30);
    } else {
        add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 30);
    }
}
add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'remove_single_add_to_cart', 25);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Получилось отключить товары по `ID` категорий, может, кому-то пригодится:

```
function my_function_remove_addtocart_category(){
   $product = get_product();
   $hide_for_categories = array( 220, 215, 213, 214, 212 );
   if ( has_term( $hide_for_categories, 'product_cat') ){    
       remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart' );
       remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 30 );
       remove_action( 'woocommerce_simple_add_to_cart', 'woocommerce_simple_add_to_cart', 30 );
       remove_action( 'woocommerce_grouped_add_to_cart', 'woocommerce_grouped_add_to_cart', 30 );
       remove_action( 'woocommerce_variable_add_to_cart', 'woocommerce_variable_add_to_cart', 30 );
       remove_action( 'woocommerce_external_add_to_cart', 'woocommerce_external_add_to_cart', 30 );
   }
}

add_action( 'wp', 'my_function_remove_addtocart_category' );
```